# Facebook Like and share Iframe are beneath the content

Tags: facebook

I have the following [site](http://www.wettgutschein.de/index.php/en/), I just added the facebook like button, but after clicking on the like button, the iframe will appear beneath the content. I also added the google share and that is working fine. What can be the problem with the like/send buton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is because in your CSS, you have `overflow:hidden` in your `#maincolumn_middle`. It will hide any elements within it, including the pop-up iframe window. Removing the `overflow:hidden` would show it.